# What smart pointer should I use in this case?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I have a class, `ResourceManifest`, which loads 3d models from a file and keeps them in a vector and then hands them out as requested. It is also possible to delete the cached 3dmodel from storage and I want my other components to be aware of this when this happens. Heres what I have now, but it dosn't satisfy my intent for sole ownership belonging to the `ResourceManifest` class

```
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Model> ModelPtr;

    class ResourceManifest
    {
    public:
        ResourceManifest(IRenderer& renderer);
        ~ResourceManifest();

        ModelPtr LoadModel(const std::string& modelName, const std::string& assetName);
        ModelPtr GetModel(const std::string& modelName);
        void DeleteModel(ModelPtr model);


    private:
        IRenderer& mRenderer;
        std::vector<ModelPtr> mModels;
        IMemoryAllocator& mMemoryAllocator;
    };
```

In my first attempt, I keep the `Model` as shared_ptrs; but the consequence is that, as implied, it is shared ownership, and I want only the copy that resides inside vector of `ResourceManifest` to be the owner. The reason I want a smart pointer is only to be able to query if the `Model` still exists, something I cannot do with raw pointers.

I am aware of weak_ptr, but I'd rather avoid its syntax if possible; I want to use it like a normal pointer if possible, like this...

```
ModelPtr modelCube = resourceManifest.GetModel("Cube");

...... later on

if (modelCube)
    modelCube->render();
```

Comment: `weak_ptr` was invented just for this situation, you shouldn't dismiss it out of hand.

Comment: I'd like to emulate its usage to be exactly like a regular pointer though if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that solves your problem is using weak_ptr's, but as I understand your question, you don't like the syntax of it.  ResourceManifest::GetModel would return a weak_ptr which you have to .lock() in order to get a shared_ptr to the Model, which if the .lock() succeeds yields a valid shared_ptr that you can use.

Another problem with the shared_ptr/weak_ptr approach that you don't mention in your question, is that ResourceManifest would not really be the owner of the Models even though it does not hand out anything but weak_ptr's.  What I mean is that there is nothing that stops a user of the ResourceManifest from elevating the weak_ptr to a shared_ptr and hold on to the shared_ptr, thus keeping it alive for longer than the ResourceManifest wants to.  In short, ResourceManifest looses control over the lifetime of the Models.

What you could do is to invent your own smart pointer, which only holds on to raw pointers:

```
MySmartPtr model = manifest.GetModel("foobar");
```

To implement the boolean test if the raw pointer is valid:

```
if (model)
```

your smart pointer could, e.g., ask ResourceManifest if the pointer is valid.  If the pointer is valid the user could use the pointer via the dereference operator of your smart pointer:

```
  model->render();
```

There is however one catch here: If your smart pointer and ResourceManifest is to be used from multiple threads, your

```
if (model)
  model->render();
```

becomes a race condition, but since your question does not mention multiple threads I will not provide you with an answer for this...

Comment: No multithreading is required. I don't understand why there is no smart pointer which fulfills my requirements of ownership, surely it must be applicable elsewhere too?

Comment: Since the shared_ptr/weak_ptr combo (together with a convention about not elevating weak_ptrs to share_ptrs) fulfills your requirements of ownership, and your requirements really is just syntactic sugar for the aforementioned combo, I am not surprised that it is not part of the C++ standard.  Besides; a scheme like the one I suggest is quite easy to implement generically.  You could also use weak_ptrs and shared_ptrs as an implementation detail of your smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own wrapper for `weak_ptr`.  Here's a simple, unfinished one to get you started.

```
template<typename T>
class weak_ptr2
{
public:
    weak_ptr2(std::shared_ptr<T> const & sp)
        :wp(sp)
    {}

    T & operator*() const { return *(wp.lock()); }
    T * operator->() const { return wp.lock().get(); }
    explicit operator bool() const { return !wp.expired(); }
private:
    std::weak_ptr<T> wp;
};
```